# image viewpager onclicklistener issue

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, onclicklistener

Used `ViewPager` for images sliding, when clicking on each image must do an action, its different action from image to another,

I'm new to android development

so I try to add `onClick` listener to `ViewPager`, but I can't achieve it,

please any suggestion how to implement `OnClickListener` so when I click the first image will do action and when click the second image will do another action and so on for all images, I have it inside the view pager

thanks in advance.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }


 }
```

ImageAdapter:

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
private int[] GalImages = new int[] {
    R.drawable.a,
    R.drawable.b,
    R.drawable.c,
    R.drawable.d,
    R.drawable.g,
    R.drawable.h,

};
ImageAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
  return GalImages.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
  return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
  intpadding=context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
  imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
  imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
  imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
  ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
  return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
  ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch click events in ViewPager you have to override onTouchListener, since default implementation is not made to handle clicks

Your MainActivity should look something like this:

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        final GestureDetector tapGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new TapGestureListener());
        mViewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                tapGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

            if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            //do your thing tied with first page
            } else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
            //do your thing tied with second page
            } else if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
            //do your thing tied with third page
            }

            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: each page, when clicked, will run different mp3 so the action of each page will be different, how to get that please, all mp3 stored on the app itself, thanks

Comment: I'm new to android, I have two red line error under (msend)  mSend.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { also under (mViewPager) in all( if & else code),please how to solve it , thanks

Comment: @frozenhill4 edited my answer, sorry i copy pasted my code, and forgot to change variable names

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
 @Override
 public Object instantiateItem(View collection, final int pos) { //have 
    to make final so we can see it inside of onClick()
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_PAGE, null);

    page.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            //this will log the page number that was click do your action 
    according to position
            Log.i("TAG", "This page was clicked: " + pos);
        }
    });


    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(page, 0);
    return page;
 }
```